# Synology NAS can only be mounted (as nfs) when connected by cable

Tags: nfs, wifi, mount, network-attached-storage

I bought a Synology NAS DS216se on Wed. Dec. 26th. After first tests with samba, which were very slow, I mounted it as nfs.
It got better. But during a huge rsync it came to my mind that probably using a cable instead of Wifi, might help speeding up...
It did (slightly) and I got no complaints during rsync switching to a wired connection.
After some more test yesterday(Dec. 30th) I restarted my computer. After that I was unable to mount the NAS as nfs. 
Always getting: "mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting"
I completely reinitialized the NAS (RESET) and tried and searched the web ... to no avail
After 10 hours of desperate search I remembered that my first mount used Wifi. Unplugged the cable and I could mount it.
Anyone knows a reason for that? And probably a solution?
I've tried several types of entries in /etc/fstab like:
NASServer://volume1/Directory /media/NAS-mount-point nfs auto 0 0

Comment: https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/tutorial/File_Sharing/How_to_access_files_on_Synology_NAS_within_the_local_network_NFS

Answer (score 0):

Linux:

If you are using named hosts (NASServer) make certain that they are defined in your /etc/hosts file, otherwise use the IP address.

Then fstab can be (one backslash, not two as you have used):

NASServer:/volume1/Directory /media/NAS-mount-point nfs auto,defaults,nofail 0 0

- Plex Forum - "[How to mount media from your NAS shares on Linux using NFS](https://forums.plex.tv/t/how-to-mount-media-from-your-nas-shares-on-linux-using-nfs/197947)"
- Unix & Linux - "[How to edit /etc/fstab properly for network drive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/178188/261962)"
- AskUbuntu - "[NFS Shares - one IP Read/Write, rest Read-Only](https://askubuntu.com/a/633930)"

Comment: Thanks, but it obviously doesn't matter if there are 2 backslashes or one (tried it)